# Clion: Error running 'makefile': Cannot build 'makefile'

Tags: c, clion

I have not seen any thread talk about this specific error so here is the problem:

I have set up a C project in Clion and I configured in `Setting -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Toolchains` a file usr/bin/make as the `Make`.

I could run my code yesterday but today, i get the warning in a red window popping-up:  `Error running 'makefile': Cannot build 'makefile'` when I try to run my code.

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) ? Show (in your question) the C code you are compiling, and the compilation command you are using (and your `Makefile`). Provide a real [mre]

Comment: Take inspiration from the (downloaded) source code of existing open source projects coded in C, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler), [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you’re trying to run the makefile instead of the program that is built by it.
Have you tried doing a build first? Or maybe you should try to clean the project too.
Have a look a the blog post of JetBrains https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/06/makefile-projects-in-clion/. There’s a gif that shows how to clean the project. Hope this helps, if not maybe post your makefile so we can check if it has any errors.